# PHP - if more variables or at least one of them equals to same value

Tags: php

Is there any better way how to write this in PHP?

```
if ($variable1 == true OR $variable2 == true OR $variable3 == true OR $variable4 == true) {
    $global_variable = true;
}
```

Comment: How are `$variableX` defined?

Comment: Better is subjective...

Comment: One hint: what's the difference between `if ($foo == true)` and `if ($foo)`?

Comment: Do you only want to set `$global_variable` to true, should the value be left alone if they are all false?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Better" is a really subjective term. For a good balance of brevity and readability, I'd suggest

```
$global_variable = ( $variable1 || $variable2 || $variable3 || $variable4 );
```

This will assign `$global_variable` true if any of `$variable1` - `$variable4` are true, or false if all of them evaluate to false.

**Edit** This will always assign a value, where OP's snippet does not assign one for the `false` case.

Comment: I was looking for a ternary option, but I think this is even better.

Comment: Waiting for OP to respond - BUT this is not the same as OP's code, this will always set the value whereas OP's code only sets it to true.

Comment: @NigelRen Very true, thank you. I'll add a note

Answer (score 2):

```
if($variable1 || $variable2 || $variable3 || $variable4){
    // your code
}
```

There is no need to use `== true` and you should use the pipe `||` operand for or

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well

```
if ($variable1 OR $variable2 OR $variable3 OR $variable4) {
    $global_variable = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
$collection = [$variable1, $variable2, $variable3, $variable4];
if (in_array(true, $collection)) {
    $global_variable = true;    
}
```

Hope it helps you ;)